# Nameserver setup

Tags: bind, nameserver

I setup bind on my debian box, and have setup my zone files to have my nameserver defined.

When I dig, using for example:

dig @123.456.789.123 ns1.mynameserver.com

where 123.456.789.123 is the defined IP of my nameserver, it resolves 100% fine with no errors. When I go to my sites which are using this nameserver on the internet, the site is not available  - but I presume this is because DNS has not propogated yet.

However, my question is, I did this all on my server only. **Is there somewhere I should register my nameserver publically**? I.e. why couldn't someone else just setup a nameserver called ns1.mynameserver.com based on their IP address?

How then would a client know which nameserver is the real authority?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that user picks which DNS server to use, or someone picks it for him/her.
Any DNS server is authoritative for its zones, and the rest it gets from public servers.

So what ISP does is register authoritative nameserver with your domain name registration, so if for some reason you want to run your own DNS you need to contact them to change it.

You can do whois lookup and see registration information, you will find nameservers there.

This doesn't mean that someone can't setup another DNS server to point your domain to another IP address, but not many users will be using that. For example DNS server in my organization is authoritative for facebook.com, but 50 people use that because I enforce it. Another example might be someone trying to hack someone else, but if you are not a bank or social network or some huge blog or magazine - don't worry about that too much.

Nice example IP address, by the way...